# How to get Javascript collection of table cells which may or may not be defined

Tags: javascript, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking existence of properties in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248664/checking-existence-of-properties-in-javascript)

I am trying to get the first row of a table's tbody cells (`i.e. this.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells`) without using jQuery.  If there are not any, I do not wish to cause an error. 
The following seems to work, but is there a better way?

```
var tbody_cells = (this.tBodies
  && this.tBodies
  && this.tBodies[0].rows
  && this.tBodies[0].rows[0])
? this.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells
:undefined;
```

Comment: @NULL I'm sure this is a very different question. OP is looking for elements, not properties, and the answer is really different.

Comment: How about simply using `this.querySelectorAll('tbody:first-child > tr:first-child > td')`? )

Comment: @raina77ow.  I didn't specify in my original question, but this.querySelectorAll was only used in IE8 and above.

Comment: And you got to support IE7 even now? ) Damn. Anyway, from all these answers I'd choose `try-catch` approach probably.

Comment: @raina77ow.  You'd do the try-catch approach over my ternary operator approach?

Comment: I'm not sure about the try/catch. I don't really like its potential to hide bugs. On the other hand, the ternary operator approach is fine as long as it's short...

Comment: @dystroy Well, the only bug here is the one that OP is actually trying to hide (with this `isset`-like chain of &&), so I guess it's ok here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a try catch block:

```
var result;
try{
result = this.tBodies[0].rows[0].cells;
}catch(e if e instanceof ReferenceError){
result = undefined;
}
```

Comment: Think this is better than my original approach?

Comment: @user1032531 It's cleaner, in that you don't have to write repetitive code, don't know about better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.querySelectorAll) :

```
this.querySelectorAll('tr:first-child td');
```

That doesn't work with IE7 but do you really care ?

If you care and frequently have to do this kind of things, I'd suggest to use a utility library, namely [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which makes this easy and takes care for you of the many compatibility pitfalls :

```
$('tr:first-child td', this);
```

Comment: Thanks dystroy.  Never knew about querySelectorAll.  I don't really care about IE6, but do care about IE7.

Comment: Though the OP's table could have several `<tbody>` section, and only the first one should be processed. ) But +1 for the obviously cleaner approach. )

Answer (score 0):

Actually I dont know if the table is always ready.

```
<html>
<body>
    <table id="tbl">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

function getTblCells() {

    var cells = document.getElementById("tbl").children[0].children[0].children;

    return children ? children : [];
}
```

You could as well give the first row an id and check once if the row exists (if you doubt its existance) and then do the 'has children' check.